# Toonami anime (2015-2018) where characters fight beasts and when they beat them the beasts turn into crystals

Tags: story-identification, anime

I don’t really remember the anime or the name of the characters but what I do remember is:

1. The characters fight beasts and when they beat them the beasts turn into crystals
2. The mc has a crystal from a wolf and the overall color is white and red
3. There is a building that turns into an airship
4. Some of the other characters’ beasts are named orochi and winged garuda
5. The mc’s family owns a bento restaurant
6. It was shown on Toonami

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Toonami

Comment: My general first thought for "capturing monsters in crystals" is *[Magi-Nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi-Nation_(TV_series))*, but that was not on Toonami, and other details don't match.

Answer (score -1):

could be one of the tenchi muyo series, theres several and all of them ran on toonami

Comment: Could you [edit] this to give it a bit more of a description of how it matches and also which one it likely is? It’s quite bare and brief at the moment.